# Mysql - What happen in my Order by?

Tags: mysql

I have table like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example 
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
primary key ( id ))
```

I insert to table 20 record from 1 -> 20 like

```
id | name
1  | example 0
2  | example 1
...
20 | example 19
```

I do query like

```
SELECT *
FROM `example`
ORDER BY `name` DESC
```

But results are

```
id | name
10 | example 9
9  | example 8
...
1  | example 0
```

**I think that is**

```
id | name
20 | example 19
19 | example 18
...
1  | example 0
```

How can I do what i think. Thanks

Comment: And you are 100% sure there are 20 records in the table? Like, really 100% sure?

Comment: It might have something to do with "natural sorting"?

Comment: @N.B. sorry I typing error I just edit my record plz see it again

Comment: @LookAtMeNow is the entire value of `name` = `20 example 19`?  What exactly is stored in the name column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to grab the number after the space with [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) and then do `ORDER BY` should work while using `CAST`.

```
SELECT   *
FROM     example
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(name,LOCATE(' ',name)+1) AS SIGNED) DESC
```

Comment: but ORDER BY (name+0) ASC and ORDER BY (name+0) DESC has same results :(?

Comment: @defaultNINJA I just edit them plz see again

Comment: @LookAtMeNow see updated answer.  may need to adjust `SUBSTRING`

Answer (score 2):

It is a string sort, not a numeric one

ASCII wise, descending, `'9'` is before `'20'` as expected. THis can also be thought of as `'9 '` (trailing space) being compared to `'20'`

String sorting is character-wise.

Comment: @defaultNINJA: It's tagged MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `example`
ORDER BY CAST(name AS UNSIGNED)desc;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04a0e/3)

Comment: The ID is just an auto-incremented field, which should not be used for sorting. In this specific case, OP is asking to sort by name. Sorting by a different field that only accedentally has the right order, does not solve the underlying problem.

Comment: @GolezTrol check now. Updated

Comment: @Praveen please see my edit results:(

Answer (score 0):

It's doing alpha ordering because it's a string.

Example 2 is after Example 1000.

Some options
You could split it in to two fields names and number
You could do a lot of messing about with String functions to split it up for a sort
You could add leading zeros Example 0002 is before Example 1000.

Answer (score -1):

You are ordering by the name which will result in an alphebetic order.  Try

```
    ORDER BY id desc;
```

Comment: The ID is just an auto-incremented field, which should not be used for sorting. In this specific case, OP is asking to sort by name. Sorting by a different field that only accedentally has the right order, does not solve the underlying problem.